# Gradle Ant Cannot add task ':myproject:test' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: ant, gradle

I'm trying to Gradle-ize our build by using Gradle to execute the Ant build.  I'm using the java plugin so I can set source/target and I'm using ant.importBuild 'build.xml'.  When I execute Gradle, I get the error above.  I understand that both Ant and Gradle have these targets/tasks in common: clean, jar, javadoc, test.  One option is to change the Ant target names in build.xml, but I'm hoping there's an easier way as I have a lot of projects and build files.  I found this "wrapper" solution (http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-771), but this did not work for me.  How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Your options are:

- Do not apply the plugin to the same project that imports the Ant build.
- Rename the conflicting targets in the Ant build script.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename all the ant targets:

```
ant.importBuild('build.xml') { String oldTargetName ->
    return 'ant_' + oldTargetName
}
```